# Finding difference based on interaction between two vectors

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames with two columns each I'd like to compare, and generate output that appears in the first dataframe only that is the difference of the interaction of the two columns when compared between the dataframes.

I've tried using merge, %in%, Interaction, match, and I can't seem to get the correct output. I've also searched extensively on SO and am not finding a similar problem.

The closest response I've found is:

```
newdat <- match(interaction(dfA$colA, dfA$colB), interaction(dfB$colA, dfB$colB))
```

But obviously, this code isn't correct as this would (if working) would give me something that is common between the dataframes, and I want the difference between them (erroring - it generates a numeric vector, when both colA and B are string).

Example data:

```
#Dataframe A

    colA     colB
    Aspirin  Smith, John
    Aspirin  Doe, Jane
    Atorva   Smith, John
    Simva    Doe, Jane

#Dataframe B
    colA     colB
    Aspirin  Smith, John
    Aspirin  Doe, Jane
    Atorva   Doe, Jane

## GOAL: 

#Dataframe
    colA     colB
    Atorva   Smith, John
    Simva    Doe, Jane
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `setdiff` from the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

setdiff(datA, datB)
#     colA        colB
# 1 Atorva Smith, John
# 2  Simva   Doe, Jane
```

**DATA**

```
datA <- read.table(text = "    colA     colB
    Aspirin  'Smith, John'
    Aspirin  'Doe, Jane'
    Atorva   'Smith, John'
    Simva    'Doe, Jane'",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

datB <- read.table(text = "    colA     colB
    Aspirin  'Smith, John'
    Aspirin  'Doe, Jane'
    Atorva   'Doe, Jane'",
                   header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Also, in `data.table`, `fsetdiff(datA, datB)` or `anti_join(datA, datB)` from `dplyr`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a base R solution, it's easy to write a `setdiffDF` function.

```
setdiffDF <- function(x, y){
  ix <- !duplicated(rbind(y, x))[nrow(y) + 1:nrow(x)]
  x[ix, ]
}


setdiffDF(dfA, dfB)
#    colA        colB
#3 Atorva Smith, John
#4  Simva   Doe, Jane
```

**Data in `dput` format.**

```
dfA <-
structure(list(colA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L), 
.Label = c("Aspirin", "Atorva", "Simva"), class = "factor"), 
colB = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("Doe, Jane", 
"Smith, John"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -4L))

dfB <-
structure(list(colA = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), 
.Label = c("Aspirin", "Atorva"), class = "factor"), 
colB = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("Doe, Jane", 
"Smith, John"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```